# Is it possible to capture all current Uncaught Exceptions handlers in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am making a Node.js exception reporter (NPM package) and I need it to work with other exception reporters (such as Raven). The problem with Raven and a few other Exceptions handlers is that it exits the process after receiving an Uncaught Exception. This makes it impossible for my exception reporter to send the exception report via http.

I want to know if it is possible to:

1. get all current running Uncaught Exceptions handlers.
2. get all upcoming Uncaught Exceptions handlers.

So basically what I want to do is to wrap around these bad boys and make sure my exception reporter runs first. Such as:

`Uncaught Exception => my exception reporter => Raven => process.exit(1);`

OR

`Uncaught Exception => my exception reporter => the project's own exception reporter => whatever it sees fit;`

AND I also need to make sure if there is no other exception reporters, we should exit the process:

`Uncaught Exception => my exception reporter => nothing => process.exit(1);`

Comment: `process` is an EventEmitter.  That's how `process.on('uncaughtException, ...)` works.  You can reach inside the EventEmitter part of the `process` object and find all the handlers registered for `uncaughtExceptions` and manipulate things to put yours first in line.  It's kind of a hack, but it could be done.  You could even monkey patch `.on` on the `process` object so you can capture any subsequent listeners for that event.

Comment: I see, let me see if I could figure out how to implement this. Sounds like it would be viable.

Answer (score 0):

`process` is an `EventEmitter`. That's how

```
process.on('uncaughtException, ...)
```

works.

You can reach inside the `EventEmitter` part of the process object and find all the handlers registered for `uncaughtExceptions` and manipulate things to put yours first in line. It's kind of a hack, but it could be done. You could even monkey patch `.on()` on the process object so you can capture any subsequent listeners for that event.

Here's a function that would remove any existing listenders for `unhandledRejection` insert yours, then add back the others so yours was guaranteed to be the first one to be called.

```
function addListenerFirstInLine(emitter, eventName, listener) {
    // get existing listeners for the target event
    const listeners = emitter.listeners(eventName);

    // remove then all
    emitter.removeAllListeners(eventName);

    // add new listener first in line
    emitter.on(eventName, listener);

    // put back prior listeners after ours
    for (const fn of listeners) {
        emitter.on(eventName, fn);
    }
}
```

And, you could then use it for your application like this:

```
addListenerFirstInLine(process, "uncaughtException", myListener)
```

Comment: @aerowang - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use process 'uncaughtException' and 'unhandledRejection' events.

Also remember that it is not safe to resume normal operation after 'uncaughtException', because the system becomes corrupted:

Example:

```
process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
    process.exit(1);
  });
```